# Adding a JPanel row to a JTable model

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, tablelayout

I am trying to add a jpanel as a row to my jtable, something that looks like this:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHaM4.png) , the red buttons are supposed to be invisible till the edit button on the top right is clicked.

I tried something like this:

```
JPanel row = new JPanel();
            row.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));
            row.setAutoscrolls(true);
            row.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
            row.setLayout(new TableLayout(new double[][]{
                    {TableLayout.FILL, TableLayout.FILL},
                    {TableLayout.PREFERRED}}));
            ((TableLayout)row.getLayout()).setHGap(0);
            ((TableLayout)row.getLayout()).setVGap(0);

            JLabel deleteRow = new JLabel();
            deleteRow.setText("");
            deleteRow.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/example/clinicsystem/pictures/remove.png")));
            JLabel rowText = new JLabel();
            rowText.setText(comboBoxPermissions.getSelectedItem().toString());
            rowText.setForeground(Color.black);
            rowText.setFont(new Font("Helvetica-Normal", Font.PLAIN, 14));
            rowText.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

            row.add(deleteRow, new TableLayoutConstraints(0, 0, 0, 0, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));
            row.add(rowText, new TableLayoutConstraints(0, 0, 0, 0, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));

            model.addRow(new JPanel[]{row});
```

but when I run the project, I get this text inside the row where this panel is supposed to be:

```
javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=info.clearthought.layout.TableLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder@254d8187,flags=33554441,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
```

Comment: You are mixing view with model in a bad way -- the JTable TableModel should not hold JPanels but rather should hold the non-GUI logical data. If you need to display functioning buttons, then the view components need to be in the table's renderer and editor, *not* the model.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how can i add them in the renderer or editor? do i need to make an entire new class or is it possible without?

Comment: There are great tutorials that explain how to use editors and renderer, and you really need to study these, as well as Camickr's answer as he is a true Swing expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get this text inside the row where this panel is supposed to be:

By default render of the table will simply invoke the `toString()` method on the data in the `TableModel`, so you see the toString() value of the JPanel.

A `JTable` is not designed to add a component to the TableModel. It is designed for you to add data to the TableModel. The data is then rendered based on the type of data added to the model.

> the red buttons are supposed to be invisible till the edit button on the top right is clicked.

So you would need to add a column of data to represent the red buttons. Start by reading [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/). It demonstrates how to add a column of buttons to the table and how to add an Action to be invoked when you click on the button.

If you don't want the column to be visible then you can remove the `TableColumn` from the `TableColumnModel`, after you create the table. Then when the "edit" button is clicked, you can add the `TableColumn` back to the `TableColumnModel`.

The `TableColumnModel` has methods like `removeTableColumn(...)` and `addTableColumn(..)` to help with this. You can also use the `getColumn(...)` method of the JTable to get the column to remove and save for future use.

Read the section from the Swing tuturial on [How to Use Table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information about renderers and editors.

Comment: is there a way to make that button column a label column instead so i can add my own icon and make it look like the picture?

Comment: @mushter: I think that the links in this answer explain *just that*. 1+

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels oops, just found it, thanks :)